# Is $f(x) > 0$ for all $x>0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Prove or disprove.

If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function, $f'(x) > f(x)$ for all $x$, and $f(0) = 0$, then $f(x) > 0$ for all $x>0$.

If I could be pointed in the right direction, it would be highly appreciated.